# distance analysis in scattered points 

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-compiler

I have randomly generated 3 set of points through scatter algorithm and the algorithm is

```
M = randi(1000,200);
AP = randi(1000,12);
BS = randi(1000,7);
scatter(M(:,1),M(:,20),21,'b.'); hold on
scatter(AP(:,1),AP(:,9),80,'k*');hold on
scatter(BS(:,1),BS(:,4),'r');hold off
```

Now, I have to set the coverage area for AP and to analyze distance between AP and M, which is within the coverage area. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if you are looking for the distance between each point in M to each point in AP you can use the function fdist2.

Comment: @BarathRavi: can you show an illustration of what you are trying to do (something hand-drawn is also fine). If I understandd this, I'm thinking you want to compute the convex hull of each set of points?

Answer (score 0):

First extract coverage area of AP:

```
ExtractedM=[M(:,1) M(:,20)];
ExtractedAP=[AP(:,1) AP(:,9)];%Just creating two different matrices for plotted points

%calculating coverage area of AP i.e. bounding box for coordinates of AP
yMax=max(ExtractedAP(:,2));
yMin=min(ExtractedAP(:,2));
xMax=max(ExtractedAP(:,1));
xMin=min(ExtractedAP(:,1));

%Finding the points from M which lie in the coverage area of AP
[positionBoundedPointsMx1,dummy]=find(ExtractedM(:,1)>=xMin & ExtractedM(:,1)<=xMax);
[positionBoundedPointsMx2,dummy]=find(ExtractedM(:,2)>=yMin & ExtractedM(:,2)<=yMax);
positionBoundedPointsMx=intersect(positionBoundedPointsMx1,positionBoundedPointsMx2,'rows');
boundedPointsM=ExtractedM(positionBoundedPointsMx,:);

%Making sure that correct sets of points in M have been extracted
scatter(M(:,1),M(:,20),21,'b.'); hold on
scatter(AP(:,1),AP(:,9),80,'k*');hold on
scatter(BS(:,1),BS(:,4),'r');hold on;
scatter(boundedPointsM(:,1),boundedPointsM(:,2),'ko');
```

Extracted points in M are represented by blue dot inside a black circle. It looks correct as all points in M lie inside the coverage area of AP.

Now, I am not sure what do you want to calculate. Assuming you just want to calculate the Euclidean distance between two points, therefore, I converted `ExtractedAP` and `boundedPointsM` into a vector and used `pdist2`

```
ExtractedAP_Vec=ExtractedAP(:);  %24x1 vector 
boundedPointsM_Vec=boundedPointsM(:);  %224x1 vector

%calculate distance between each point of 'ExtractedAP_Vec' and every point in 'boundedPointsM_Vec'.
dist_AP_M=pdist2(ExtractedAP_Vec,boundedPointsM_Vec);
```

P.S. Plot the scatter plots and verify by yourself. I cannot post images here, sorry.

Comment: Hi,   In my coding M-Mobile user, AP is Access Point. Now I want select any one AP and have to set an coverage area(diameter) for tat AP and to find the distance from AP to M (Which are within the coverage area).     plz help me......